# Why the browsers take shades of blue while selecting?

Tags: html

Why the browsers take shades of blue (colors specified in SO post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16094837/what-is-the-browser-default-background-color-when-selecting-text)) while we select the text ?

Is there any special reason for the same ?

Note:Question moved from [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31181923/disable-blue-background-and-highlight-only-the-text-in-html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most browsers take the standard selection color of the operating system. This color is chosen to be consistent with the rest of the operating system.

If you use Windows that color is blue, with Ubuntu for example the selection color is orange. And you will see that the selection color in browsers in Ubuntu the selection color is also orange.
[image: Browser selection in Ubuntu]

Comment: Much better than my answer!

Answer (score 0):

The color of the text highlight can be changed using the CSS pseudo element '::selection'.

Therefor, I would guess (and it is just a guess) that the blue color was chosen simply because it worked as a part of the browsers default (without site or user CSS) color scheme.

Comment: thank you @AndrewMartin but different browsers are developed using different technologies then how come every browser takes blueshades,correct me if im wrong was curious to know that..

Comment: Like I said, my answer is no more than an educated guess. - As for why the default color schems are the same, I think that probably goes back to Tim Berners-Lee or someone he was working with at the time they developed the first protocols and browsers.